# Basic Win32 WebView2 example not working in pure C

Tags: c++, c, winapi, webview2

A new problem blows my mind lately: a very simple code using the WebView2 library from Microsoft works if compiled as C++ but not as C. What could be causing the problem? I tried all sorts of fixes, like using an older version of the WebView2 library, using Edge Canary or beta or a different version of WebView2 Runtime, it simply refuses to work.

Here is the sample code in C:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#include <Shlobj_core.h>
#include "WebView2.h"

#define APPLICATION_NAME TEXT("WebView2")

#define error_printf printf

ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler* envHandler;
ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler* completedHandler;
HWND hWnd = NULL;
ICoreWebView2Controller* webviewController = NULL;
ICoreWebView2* webviewWindow = NULL;
BOOL bEnvCreated = FALSE;

ULONG HandlerRefCount = 0;
ULONG HandlerAddRef(IUnknown* This)
{
    return ++HandlerRefCount;
}
ULONG HandlerRelease(IUnknown* This)
{
    --HandlerRefCount;
    if (HandlerRefCount == 0)
    {
        if (completedHandler)
        {
            free(completedHandler->lpVtbl);
            free(completedHandler);
        }
        if (envHandler)
        {
            free(envHandler->lpVtbl);
            free(envHandler);
        }
    }
    return HandlerRefCount;
}
HRESULT HandlerQueryInterface(
    IUnknown* This,
    IID* riid,
    void** ppvObject
)
{
    *ppvObject = This;
    HandlerAddRef(This);
    return S_OK;
}
HRESULT HandlerInvoke(
    IUnknown* This,
    HRESULT errorCode,
    void* arg
)
{
    if (!bEnvCreated)
    {
        bEnvCreated = TRUE;
        char ch;
        completedHandler = malloc(sizeof(ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler));
        if (!completedHandler)
        {
            error_printf(
                "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
                __FILE__,
                __LINE__,
                "Cannot allocate ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler",
                GetLastError()
            );
            ch = _getch();
            return GetLastError();
        }
        completedHandler->lpVtbl = malloc(sizeof(ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandlerVtbl));
        if (!completedHandler->lpVtbl)
        {
            error_printf(
                "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
                __FILE__,
                __LINE__,
                "Cannot allocate ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandlerVtbl",
                GetLastError()
            );
            ch = _getch();
            return GetLastError();
        }
        completedHandler->lpVtbl->AddRef = HandlerAddRef;
        completedHandler->lpVtbl->Release = HandlerRelease;
        completedHandler->lpVtbl->QueryInterface = HandlerQueryInterface;
        completedHandler->lpVtbl->Invoke = HandlerInvoke;

        ICoreWebView2Environment* env = arg;
        env->lpVtbl->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(
            env,
            hWnd,
            completedHandler
        );
    }
    else
    {
        ICoreWebView2Controller* controller = arg;

        if (controller != NULL) {
            webviewController = controller;
            webviewController->lpVtbl->get_CoreWebView2(
                webviewController,
                &webviewWindow
            );
        }

        ICoreWebView2Settings* Settings;
        webviewWindow->lpVtbl->get_Settings(
            webviewWindow,
            &Settings
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_IsScriptEnabled(
            Settings,
            TRUE
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(
            Settings,
            TRUE
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_IsWebMessageEnabled(
            Settings,
            TRUE
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_AreDevToolsEnabled(
            Settings,
            FALSE
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled(
            Settings,
            TRUE
        );
        Settings->lpVtbl->put_IsStatusBarEnabled(
            Settings,
            TRUE
        );

        RECT bounds;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
        webviewController->lpVtbl->put_Bounds(
            webviewController,
            bounds
        );

        webviewWindow->lpVtbl->Navigate(
            webviewWindow,
            L"https://google.com/"
        );
    }

    return S_OK;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND   hWnd,
    _In_ UINT   uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    /*case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
    {
        return 0;
    }*/
    case WM_DPICHANGED:
    {
        RECT* const newWindowSize = (RECT*)(lParam);
        SetWindowPos(
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            newWindowSize->left,
            newWindowSize->top,
            newWindowSize->right - newWindowSize->left,
            newWindowSize->bottom - newWindowSize->top,
            SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        if (webviewController != NULL) {
            RECT bounds;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
            webviewController->lpVtbl->put_Bounds(
                webviewController,
                bounds
            );
        };
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        return DefWindowProc(
            hWnd,
            uMsg,
            wParam,
            lParam
        );
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    int ch;

    FILE* conout;
    AllocConsole();
    freopen_s(
        &conout,
        "CONOUT$",
        "w",
        stdout
    );

    HRESULT hr;

    if (!SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(
        DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2
    ))
    {
        error_printf(
            "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
            __FILE__,
            __LINE__,
            "SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext",
            GetLastError()
        );
        ch = _getch();
        return GetLastError();
    }

    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        error_printf(
            "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
            __FILE__,
            __LINE__,
            "CoInitialize",
            hr
        );
        ch = _getch();
        return hr;
    }

    WNDCLASS wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = APPLICATION_NAME;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        (LPCWSTR)(
            MAKEINTATOM(
                RegisterClass(&wndClass)
            )
            ),
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 800, 800,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        error_printf(
            "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
            __FILE__,
            __LINE__,
            "CreateWindowEx",
            GetLastError()
        );
        ch = _getch();
        return GetLastError();
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);

    envHandler = malloc(sizeof(ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler));
    if (!envHandler)
    {
        error_printf(
            "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
            __FILE__,
            __LINE__,
            "Cannot allocate ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler",
            GetLastError()
        );
        ch = _getch();
        return GetLastError();
    }
    envHandler->lpVtbl = malloc(sizeof(ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandlerVtbl));
    if (!envHandler->lpVtbl)
    {
        error_printf(
            "%s:%d: %s (0x%x).\n",
            __FILE__,
            __LINE__,
            "Cannot allocate ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandlerVtbl",
            GetLastError()
        );
        ch = _getch();
        return GetLastError();
    }
    envHandler->lpVtbl->AddRef = HandlerAddRef;
    envHandler->lpVtbl->Release = HandlerRelease;
    envHandler->lpVtbl->QueryInterface = HandlerQueryInterface;
    envHandler->lpVtbl->Invoke = HandlerInvoke;
    
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        envHandler
    );

    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(
        &msg,
        NULL,
        0,
        0)) != 0)
    {
        // An error occured
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I simply used `lpVtbl` where appropiate and provided proper callbacks. The code is a bit more compact in C++:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wil/com.h>
#include "WebView2.h"

#define APPLICATION_NAME TEXT("WebView2")

static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND   hwnd,
    _In_ UINT   uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DPICHANGED:
    {
        RECT* const newWindowSize = (RECT*)(lParam);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd,
            NULL,
            newWindowSize->left,
            newWindowSize->top,
            newWindowSize->right - newWindowSize->left,
            newWindowSize->bottom - newWindowSize->top,
            SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        if (webviewController != NULL) {
            RECT bounds;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &bounds);
            webviewController->put_Bounds(bounds);
        };
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        return DefWindowProc(
            hwnd,
            uMsg,
            wParam,
            lParam
        );
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR pCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
)
{
    SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(
        DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2
    );

    WNDCLASS wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = APPLICATION_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wndClass);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 800, 800,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(
        hWnd,
        nCmdShow
    );
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(NULL, NULL, NULL,
        Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
            [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT {

                // Create a CoreWebView2Controller and get the associated CoreWebView2 whose parent is the main window hWnd
                env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(hWnd, Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
                    [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller) -> HRESULT {
                        if (controller != nullptr) {
                            webviewController = controller;
                            webviewController->get_CoreWebView2(&webviewWindow);
                        }

                        // Add a few settings for the webview
                        // The demo step is redundant since the values are the default settings
                        ICoreWebView2Settings* Settings;
                        webviewWindow->get_Settings(&Settings);
                        Settings->put_IsScriptEnabled(TRUE);
                        Settings->put_AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled(TRUE);
                        Settings->put_IsWebMessageEnabled(TRUE);
                        Settings->put_AreDevToolsEnabled(FALSE);
                        //Settings->put_AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled(FALSE);
                        Settings->put_IsStatusBarEnabled(FALSE);

                        // Resize WebView to fit the bounds of the parent window
                        RECT bounds;
                        GetClientRect(hWnd, &bounds);
                        webviewController->put_Bounds(bounds);
                        webviewController->put_ZoomFactor(0.8);

                        // Schedule an async task to navigate to Bing
                        webviewWindow->Navigate(HOME_PAGE);

                        // Step 4 - Navigation events

                        // Step 5 - Scripting

                        // Step 6 - Communication between host and web content

                        return S_OK;
                    }).Get());
                return S_OK;
            }).Get());

    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(
        &msg,
        NULL,
        0,
        0)) != 0)
    {
        // An error occured
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Since I have now stumbled upon this, I am really curious what may be causing this. Why does it matter in the end? Thanks for any pointers.

It does not work means the web page is not displayed. The window is blank. The WebView2 actually is not displayed on the window.

Edit:

What are `wil::com_ptr`s actually? If I change this:

```
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller> webviewController;
static wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> webviewWindow;
```

To this:

```
static ICoreWebView2Controller* webviewController;
static ICoreWebView2* webviewWindow;
```

In C++, I break it. Why? Just why? (I replaced the callbacks `Microsoft::WRL::Callback` with standalone classes and, naturally, it still worked, but getting rid of the COM pointers and using regular pointers breaks it. Why...?

Comment: The web page is not displayed. The window is blank. The WebView2 actually is not displayed on the window.

Comment: That's bogus. COM's ABI has two language-level requirements: `1` Create structures of pointers. `2` Call functions through pointers. C meets those requirements. If a COM interface can be consumed by C++, it can be consumed by C just as well.

Comment: What would be an actual on-point technical reason for that? The MIDL compiler generated a header file with interfaces for C as well. The code compiles just fine. Calling COM from C is totally possible. Calling Windows Runtime APIs from C is totally possible, even though many believe it is not. Technical differences between the two, of course there are, I am curious what the difference is in this particular case. Generally, yes, it surprises me when stuff does not work in C but works in C++ or any other language.

Comment: @IInspectable that's what i believe as well; and indeed, the calls work just fine... My callbacks work, they get called. I get to the main loop, yet no WebView is added to the window... it seems to me that it is something in their library, but I don't know what.

Comment: @IInspectable can you check the Edit I made regarding the COM pointers? Do you have any idea? If I use regular pointers instead of `wil::com_ptr` in C++, I break it there as well. Any idea why?

Comment: Haven't had time to look at the code yet, although that sounds like there's an issue with reference counts. Try to artificially bump them by one, by calling `AddRef`.

Comment: @rob `com_ptr` isn't part of COM. It's a C++ library implementation that manages reference counts for you. There is no requirement to use this, or *any* C++ library for COM. COM is decidedly language-agnostic. And it is, decidedly, compatible with C. Always has been, and always will be.

Comment: It should be possible to use C. I'd recommend a few things: Check the HRESULT return value from calls to Create..Controller/Environment as well as the errorCode param of your Invoke callback. Explicitly check IIDs in your QueryInterface implementation as different incompatible versions of the WebView2 API have used different IIDs for the same interface and by always returning S_OK you may be indicating to WebView2 you're using an older incompatible version. Check if any msedgewebview2.exe processes start. Check if a webview2 HWND is child of your HWND (via accexplorer32 or inspect or similar)

Comment: Please check my edit in the OP above. I have narrowed down the issue: if I use regular pointers instead of `com_ptr` for `webviewController` and `webviewWindow`, I break it in C++ as well. Now, I don't understand why that happens...

Comment: You use COM object's AddRef and Release methods to control their lifetime. When you store a copy of a pointer to a COM object in your own pointer you should call AddRef on the COM object. When you clear or change that pointer you should call Release on the COM object that is no longer referenced by that pointer. winrt::com_ptr does that automatically for you. If you don't AddRef the Environment or Controller you receive in the Invoke callback their refcount will go down to 0 after your callback and will destroy themselves.

Comment: "seems like posting here is a waste of time" "my part works just fine" "the calls work just fine" "it is something in their library" -- you are a very negative person who won't put in any work to debug their code and instead blame both the library and the Stack Overflow community, despite the fact that everyone else seems to be able to use the web view just fine.

Comment: The logic is different in the two versions. In the C version it looks like `HandlerInvoke` is expecting to be called twice, once to "create the environment" (when `bEnvCreated` is false), and once to actually initialise the web browser. In the C++ version it looks like the web browser is created by the callback immediately.

Comment: It is not different, there are 2 callbacks in C++ as well. And I have ported those to standalone structs/interfaces where I implement the Invoke manually as well. The problem is not there, as i said in the edit above, the C++ breaks as well if `com_ptr`s are replaced by regular pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, if one actually takes a minute to look a bit on the correctness and logic of the code, rather than suggesting generics and commenting just so that the patch cables have some bytes to carry around. This section has to be modified a bit: since I use `controller` after the function returns, and without using smart pointers, I have to increase its reference count so that the library knows I use it and does not free it after the `Invoke` function body is executed. Of course, when you do the assignment in the version with smart pointers, this is automatically done in the background. Unfortunately, I overlooked this, not being that aware this happens. Things like these is the reason I write these ports in C, so that I take an in-depth look and better understand how stuff works from top to bottom. 'It can't be done' without an actual reason is not a valid answer for me.

Anyway, here is the fixed version:

```
if (controller != NULL) {
    webviewController = controller;
    webviewController->lpVtbl->get_CoreWebView2(
        webviewController,
         &webviewWindow
    );
    webviewController->lpVtbl->AddRef(webviewController); // <-- here, increase the reference count for the webviewController
}
```

That's it. many thanks to the guy who helped me out: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1124

Comment: It increments the reference count for `webviewWindow`, because you "get that CoreWebView2 from it". The problem is, `webviewController`'s reference count stays the same, so when the function returns, the library sees that I haven't used it and discards it. This is consistent with C++, where the sample fails if I simply replace the `com_ptr`s with simple pointers. Then, if I increase the reference count of `webviewController` there as described above, it works too. So, why is the explanaition wrong then, it makes sense to me.

Comment: My '0' reference count is for my handlers, the library does not care about those, it is me that I manage them so that number does not really matter since I pretty much keep them however I like (I have now since made them static, so the number means nothing, I never deallocate anything). The library does not care about the handler. But it cares whether I actually 'took ownership' let's say or used the webviewController. If I don't signal so, it simply deallocates it, automatically, as it probably uses smart pointers too and that's "automatic" thing is what smart pointers are all about anyway.